# Drag along the timeline without update animation

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

Is there any way to drag along the timeline without update animation? Like the MMB drag in Maya. This is very useful to insert keyframes keeping the pose of the object.

Comment: Is there a problem with duplicating keyframe registrations to a new frame?  I think this might be a case where changing your workflow might be the wisest idea.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan ! I just tried the duplicate keyframe and it's a great alternative to the Maya MMB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way is to select the keyframes and Shift+D to duplicate them, as @Nathan mentioned.